# Resize of DIV causes page to randomly vertically scroll, FIX for Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI's Collapse and I am currently trying to fix some issue regarding automatic scrolling. To simplify my case, imagine having two DIVs one on top of the other.

The first DIV can be collapsed by the user and when so, I want the focus to be on top of the second DIV. To do that, I use jQuery's animate, however after calling *animate*, the DIV's focus is set to kind of a random position.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = null;

  $scope.doCollapse = function() {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;

    var $target = $('.tallDiv');
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, "fast");
  }
});
```

Test it with the link below:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqYQpa

One solution is, of course, to remove the *animate* part. That works ok only if you are on top of the page, if you have scrolled down already, then the focus is just set to a random point of the second DIV after the first is collapsed.

I suppose that the interaction of jQuery and Angular is not so good, is there a way to do that purely in Angular?

Comment: This happens because you are calling `$target.offset().top` before the animation to collapse the green div starts (so it returns the offset position with the green div at full height). To fix this, check the offset value after the animation has finished (or subtract the height of the green div from the offsetTop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A clean solution would be to do that after the animation, but how can I know when the animation is over? As far as I know, Angular's UI Collapse has no animation over event. I will give a shot to manually subtracting the height of the first div.

Comment: Try animating the height of the div instead of the scroll and using the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event

Comment: as for now it worked ok with removing the size of the first DIV before doing the animation. If I have time I will try to use this transitionend event. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = null;

  $scope.doCollapse = function() {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;

    var $target = $('.tallDiv');
    var $topDiv = $('.containerResizeDiv');
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top - $topDiv.height()}, "fast");
  }
});
```

As for now I solved the issue as quantum suggested. Removing the height of the first DIV before calling animation. The solution worked ok for my case but no 100%, I found some glitch.

Apparently a transitionend event exists in CSS which could be listened in order to launch the scroll animation after Collapse has ended. However I did not have time to explore that.